# Split a vector based on another partition

Tags: r, split

Suppose I have a partition defined by

```
#Partition elements of vec into adjacent chunks of size 2
vec = seq(10)
partition = split(vec,(seq_along(vec)-1) %/% 2)

$`0`
[1] 1 2

$`1`
[1] 3 4

$`2`
[1] 5 6

$`3`
[1] 7 8

$`4`
[1]  9 10
```

Now suppose that I have two (or more) additional vectors

```
vec2 = c(1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10)
vec3 = c(1,2,3,6,7,8,9,11,12)
```

For `vec2` and `vec3` how can I partition it such that it mimics the natural partition of `vec` and disregards either singletons or values not in `vec`?

For `vec2`:

```
$`0`
[1] 1 2

$`1`
[1] 3 

$`2`
[1] 5 6

$`3`
[1] 7 

$`4`
[1]  9 10
```

And similarly for `vec3`:

```
$`0`
[1] 1 2

$`1`
[1] 3 

$`2`
[1] 6

$`3`
[1] 7 8

$`4`
[1]  9 

$`5`
[1]  11

$`6`
[1]  12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can loop through the `partition`

```
lapply(partition, function(x) vec2[vec2 %in% x])
```

and for 'vec3'

```
lst <- lapply(partition, function(x) vec3[vec3 %in% x])
 c(lst, as.list(vec3[!vec3 %in% unlist(lst)]))
```

This can be convertedd to a function

```
splitFun <- function(vecN, partitionlist) {
   lst <- lapply(partitionList, function(x) vecN[vecN %in% x])
   c(lst, as.list(vecN[!vecN %in% unlist(lst)]))
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's more or less the same idea as akrun had, but a bit shorter:

```
apply_partition <- function(vec, partition) {
  c(lapply(partition, intersect, x = vec),     # Elements contained in the partition
    as.list(setdiff(vec, unlist(partition))))  # Singletons which are not in the partition
}
```

Examples:

```
> apply_partition(vec2, partition)
$`0`
[1] 1 2

$`1`
[1] 3

$`2`
[1] 5 6

$`3`
[1] 7

$`4`
[1]  9 10

> apply_partition(vec3, partition)
$`0`
[1] 1 2

$`1`
[1] 3

$`2`
[1] 6

$`3`
[1] 7 8

$`4`
[1] 9

[[6]]
[1] 11

[[7]]
[1] 12
```

The list item names for the singletons are different, but if this matters, I think you can easily modify this.

Answer (score 0):

When using split, you are creating a vector of groups from the elements in `vec`; it's possible to modify those groups for vec2 and vec3.

```
vec = seq(10)
vec2 = c(1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10)
vec3 = c(1,2,3,6,7,8,9,11,12)

groups <- (seq_along(vec)-1) %/% 2
split(vec, groups)
split(vec2, groups[match(vec2, vec)])
split(vec3, groups[match(vec3, vec)])
```

For `vec3` the pattern is a bit unclear... you mention that you wish to exclude values not in `vec`, but your example seems to run contrary to that. The above code will exclude values not in `vec`, but groups can be modified based on how you want to treat elements that are not in `vec`.